# how to save mysql queries automatically when a query is executed using command line terminal?

Tags: command-line, mysql

what I am trying here is, I want to save mysql queries and output of that queries in a file and also to show on the ubuntu terminal.
My approach is like this:

```
$ mysql -u user -pmysql |& tee day1.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
use AUDIT;
select * from CUSTOMERS;
```

But it is not showing output until I press ctrl + D.It seems it sending my queries to mysql server.I want to see output of queries as well in terminal, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When `mysql`'s output isn't a terminal, it assumes non-interactive usage, and waits for input to end before executing it. You can use the `--tee` option (or the related `tee` command within `mysql` itself). From [`man mysql`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mysql.1.html):

```
--tee=file_name

Append a copy of output to the given file. This option works only in interactive mode.
the section called “MYSQL COMMANDS”, discusses tee files further.

...

tee [file_name], \T [file_name]

By using the --tee option when you invoke mysql, you can log statements and their
output. All the data displayed on the screen is appended into a given file. This can
be very useful for debugging purposes also.  mysql flushes results to the file after
each statement, just before it prints its next prompt. Tee functionality works only in
interactive mode.

You can enable this feature interactively with the tee command. Without a parameter,
the previous file is used. The tee file can be disabled with the notee command.
Executing tee again re-enables logging.
```

So:

```
mysql -u user -pmysql --tee=day1.sql
```